# notification at a given date - IntentService?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager

I have written a small note program. Now I want to make it possible to add a reminder to each note (DD.MM.YY HH:MM). When the selected date has come, there should be a notification in the notification bar. If someone clicks on the notification, it should open that note.

My idea: I could make a (Intent)Service which runs all the time in background with alarm manager. That service (without app) has to be started after booting up.

Is there any better way like using the calender?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way other than 'AlarmManager' class.

The AlarmManager doesn’t persist alarms; therefore, when the device reboots, you must set up the alarms again. If you don’t set up your alarms again, they simply don’t fire, because, to Android, they don’t exist.

You have to persistently store the remainder time of each note. And you have to register your application for boot notification. When the boot broadcast is received, the receiver needs to retrieve the stored notes and loop through each task and schedule an alarm for it, to ensure that your alarms don’t get lost in the reboot.